# Zoom In at mouse location and Zoom out at center of Canvas (Not using ScaleTransform)

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, zooming

I am writing a small drawing app in WPF. I am using `DrawingVisual` class to render shapes on `Canvas`.

I want to implement zoom In/Out for the `Canvas` control.

1) When I zoom in, zoom focus should be the mouse location.

2) When I zoom out, zoom focus should be the center of `Canvas`.

Below is the current code that I am trying but results are not satisfactory.

When I zoom out all shapes are moving towards the scaled/zoomed center location and not to the Canvas's actual center location.

So please guide me how should I compute the offset X and Y so that shapes will move towards center of canvas.

```
double zoomFactor = 1.1;
double offsetX = 0;
double offsetY = 0;
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{                
    double absoluteMouseX;
    double absoluteMouseY;               
    double centerX = this.ActualWidth / 2; //Canvas center X
    double centerY = this.ActualHeight / 2; // Canvas center Y

    Point relativeMouseToCanvas = e.GetPosition(this);                          

    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
            absoluteMouseX = relativeMouseToCanvas.X * this.Zoom + offsetX;
            absoluteMouseY = relativeMouseToCanvas.Y * this.Zoom + offsetY;

            this.Zoom *= zoomFactor;

            offsetX = absoluteMouseX - relativeMouseToCanvas.X * this.Zoom;
            offsetY = absoluteMouseY - relativeMouseToCanvas.Y * this.Zoom;
    }

    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
            absoluteMouseX = centerX * this.Zoom + offsetX;
            absoluteMouseY = centerY * this.Zoom + offsetY;

            this.Zoom /= zoomFactor;

            offsetX = absoluteMouseX - centerX * this.Zoom;
            offsetY = absoluteMouseY - centerY * this.Zoom;
     }

     // Refresh/Repaint shapes on canvas          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zooming out, in your case, will translate the upper-left corner of the viewing rectangle.

[image]

It is quite clear on the scheme that :
   ∆x = the difference of width between R1 and R2.
so ∆x = (canvas width) * zoom for R2 -  (canvas width) * zoom for R1

same goes for ∆y :
∆y = (canvas height) * zoom for R2 -  (canvas height) * zoom for R1